# FlashDevelop error creating APK for simple project

Tags: android, actionscript-3, actionscript, apk

Apk cannot be build because of errors, some obvious troubleshooting doesnt fix it

I start an AIR Mobile AS3 App project. Finally I can say it correctly found its AIR and Flex folders. There have been threads about such issues but not with  latest versions of Flex and mostly with AIR. So a new project with latest flex and AIR, I installed the AppMan package Flex SDK + AIR SDK 4.6.0. + 32.0.0

Obvious paths in the SetupSDK.bat are:

```
..(whatever drive)\FlashDevelop-5.3.3\Apps\flexairsdk\4.6.0+32.0.0
..(whatever drive)\FlashDevelop-5.3.3\Tools\android (that includes platform-tools containing adb.exe)
```

… and so application.xml must have ?
application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/32.0"

defaults in 28.0 but that changes nothing

Yes certificate is created from the bat

And that's it, a simple embedded image display:
I have to switch between Debug and Release when pressing F5 because repeating twice Debug or Repeat causes the error that var value for image is empty, but if you alternate it displays image in Device window so i will assume it compiles well.

Or deleting the `project.swf` generated on compilation also allows to display the image if running Debug or Release for first time.

But t he error is when running the PackageApp.bat and [1] for normal apk

Comment: Show the AS3 code part that causes the error `var value for image is empty`. Are you... well, whatever you're doing. For a faster answer: Start by showing some code that re-creates this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.flashdevelop.org/community/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=12144

This solved the issue. I had to install JRE 1.6 too since 1.8 has bugs with FD. set the path for java.home in jvm.config to use the JRE 1.6 folder, no more 'Variable not defined', it was common message, and now I can F5 without the error, thanks for the above tips for Bitmap still.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your code at: http://oneclickpaste.com/26534/

In `Main.as` try to close the import with a `;` (just in case it's giving a weird technical issue). 
example: `import com.mee.ptest.PicTest;`

In `PicTest.as` you need to fix this line: `iPic = new PicTest.cTestPic();` 
To become as: `iPic = new cTestPic() as Bitmap;`.

Example for `PicTest.as`:

```
package com.mee.ptest 
{
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class PicTest extends Sprite 
    {
        [Embed(source="../../../assets/testpic.jpg")]
        private static var cTestPic :Class;
        private var iPic :Bitmap;               

        public function PicTest()  
        {
            iPic = new cTestPic() as Bitmap;
            addChild(iPic);
        }

    }

}
```

And then example for `Main.as`:

```
import flash.desktop.NativeApplication;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.StageAlign;
import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
import flash.ui.Multitouch;
import flash.ui.MultitouchInputMode;
import flash.display.Bitmap;

import flash.display.*; 
import com.mee.ptest.PicTest;

public class Main extends Sprite 
{   
    public var pic : PicTest;

    public function Main() 
    {
        stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
        stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
        stage.addEventListener(Event.DEACTIVATE, deactivate);

        Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;

        //# check if app is ready to display visual items...
        if (stage) {  show_Pic(); }
        else { addEventListener( Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, show_Pic ); }

    }

    private function show_Pic() :void 
    {
        pic = new PicTest();
        addChild(pic);
    }

    private function deactivate(e:Event) :void 
    {
        // make sure the app behaves well (or exits) when in background
        //NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, the code improvements work as well. Then it's a FlashDevelop bug that after displaying the image with F5, repeating that causes error even using your code version? ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable PicTest_cTestPic is not defined.

It doesn't matter though this is a test only, I need to see how it behaves on the actual phone. And my question was why it fails to compile the apk

Comment: It fails to compile the APK because you can't say `iPic = new PicTest.cTestPic();`. Also the error `var value for image is empty` does not seem useful. Do you have a log or screenshot of the stuff going on to give that error during compile? All the error tells me is that there is something called `image` which expects a variable as value but it was left empty (not defined), like it's seeing your code like `image = ... ;` where the `...` is a blank/empty space.. Yes loading image from a Class is basic. You're the only one on planet Earth getting this mysterious error. Maybe I'll learn something

Comment: Hi, sorry I missed correcting the `iPic = new cTestPic() as Bitmap;` now it's fixed and still displays the image the 1st time, then again gives the same error the next time I F5 to test, here is the full error, I did make the rest of the code like you

`ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable com.mee.ptest::PicTest_cTestPic is not defined.
 at com.mee.ptest::PicTest$cinit()
 at global$init()
 at Main/show_Pic()
 at Main()`

Comment: http://ge.tt/8KeH73x2 Updated, this is a test project and can be used however anyone wants

 the image fails to load only after repeating the F5 test on the same mode Release/Debug of I do once Debug once Release it will display the image without the errors